# Eclipse is overriding my manual dependency defined in MANIFEST.MF

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, wildfly, manifest.mf

I am working with Eclipse Luna and WildFly 8.2.1.

In WildFly the jTDS JDBC Driver is installed as a module. The module's name is **net.sourceforge.jtds**.

I have an enterprise application with XDoclet (using EJB 2.1) which is deployed this way:

- AppEar.ear (an Enterprise Application Project in Eclipse)

  - AppEjb.jar (a EJB Project in Eclipse)
  - AppEjbClient.jar (a EJB Client Project in Eclipse)
  - AppWeb.war (a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse)
  - lib

    - AppSrc.jar (a Java EE Utility Project in Eclipse)

AppSrc.jar needs **net.sourceforge.jtds** module to work. So I open its `MAINFEST.MF` file in META-INF folder, and manually add a dependency to this way:
`Dependencies: net.sourceforge.jtds`.

So this is how `MAINFEST.MF` file looks in Eclipse:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Class-Path: ../AppEjbClient.jar 
Dependencies: net.sourceforge.jtds
```

Now AppSrc.jar also needs some 3rd-party jars which I have added in the Deployment Assembly page of AppSrc project.

When I do Build All and deploy to WildFly I see that Eclipse override the `MAINFEST.MF` file by including the 3rd-party jars. This is how `MAINFEST.MF` file look inside the AppSr.jar:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: ../AppEjbClient.jar commons-collections-3.2.jar common
 s-lang-2.3.jar commons-logging-1.1.jar richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar 
 richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.3.Final.jar ri
 chfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final.jar
```

So the Deployment Assembly has overridden the Dependencies line.

How do I add a dependency in Eclipse so that Eclipse does not override it?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem in a Maven build.